# How to append to Redux state

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm trying to append to my redux state, but having an issue understanding where I'm wrong.  At the moment, I'm getting an error `state is not iterable`.

[image]

**reducer**

```
const CURRENT_USER = "CURRENT_USER";

const reducer = (state = [], action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case CURRENT_USER:
      const currentUser = [
        ...state,
        action.payload
      ];
      return currentUser;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default reducer;
```

**dispatch**

```
posts.forEach((post: BlogPost) => {
  if (post.userId === currentUserPosts) {
    dispatch({
      type: "CURRENT_USER",
      payload: { ...post },
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: can you show how you initialize your reducer?

Comment: what is your state structure? state has currentUser object? if so. you should return {...state,state.currentUser:action.payload}

Comment: Is your state an array of objects? What is the structure of `post`? Have you tried `return [...state, action.payload]` directly, without creating the constant `currentUser`?

Comment: If you want to have `currentUser` variable inside the state, then maybe you can define your initial state as `state={currentUser: []}`, and then the action performs `return {...state, currentUser: [...state.currentUser, action.payload]}`

Comment: Why you use array to store an sigle object?  I think is more easy using `state = {currentUser: null}` and when you update store `case CURRENT_USER: return { ...state, currentUser: action.payload };`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So from the reducer after updating the state you have to return the new state

so as I see

```
case CURRENT_USER:
    return {
      currentUser: [...state, action.payload]
    }
.....
```

You are returning an object `{currentUser: [..}` this will be the new state after the action happens

so again if you call this, `state` is an object (`{currentUser: [..}`) if you try to treat that as iterable (array) you will get this error

```
[...{currentUser: []}]
```

Comment: I'm definitely losing here.  I can't figure out how to have the `currentUser` as the parent and continue appending to the array of objects.

Comment: Ok, I've updated my reducer, but I'm still not getting the result i'm looking for.

Comment: @pingeyeg What sort of state do you need? I mean the structure? for EX: `{currentUser: {name: 'ping', age: 19}, posts: []}`